# How to select MAX value in Codeigniter?

Tags: html, sql, codeigniter

I trying to show the MAX value of a field in my codeigniter, but still confuse to showing it.

I've try some answer in stackoverflow but still not work to implementing in my project.

this is my model

```
public function getCountIdMember(){
        $this->db->select_max('id_member');
        $this->db->from('member');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();        
}
```

this is my controller

```
public function validation(){
$data['member'] = $this->Member_model->getCountIdMember();
}
```

This is my view

```
<?= $member['id_member']; ?>
```

I expect the output value in my view is (id_member) example 97 or more. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, in your model

```
public function getCountIdMember(){
        $this->db->select_max('id_member');
        $this->db->from('member');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
           return $query->row('id_member');        
        }else{
           return 1;
        }
}
```

Contorller:

```
public function validation(){
      $data = array();
      $data['member'] = $this->Member_model->getCountIdMember();//here you can get only your id
      //echo var_dump($data);die;
      $this->load->view('yourViewName',$data);

}
```

View:

```
<?php echo $member;?>
```

Comment: I've try and I found output, array(1) { ["member"]=> array(1) { ["id_member"]=> string(1) "4" } } , I think it right, but in my view still not yet showing, thanks before

Comment: I just updated my code, please check and let me know what do you face?

Comment: It works, thanks you for your help sir, It's helpfully

Comment: your welcome, please kindly accept the answer and upvote so other users also find an answer easily

Comment: Still can't up vote,becasue I new member, just can accepting

Answer (score 0):

Try it:-

```
public function getCountIdMember(){
    $this->db->select_max('id_member');
    $this->db->from('member');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();
}
```

and Controller:-

```
public function validation(){
  $data = array();
  $data['member'] = $this->Member_model->getCountIdMember();
}
```

view:-

```
<?= $member->id_member; ?>
```